# Faild to add Liquidity in pancake router

Tags: solidity, remix, pancakeswap

I've forked this pancake router contract in BSC testnet
https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x9Ac64Cc6e4415144C455BD8E4837Fea55603e5c3#code

and this is mine:
https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xbcb064139d2e923f8598351bbcec9e8443825321

when I try to test addLiquidityEth in original contract it work well.

but when I try mine I get this error appear in Metamask
[image]

**what am I messing?**

Comment: You are using custom `factory` and `WETH` addresses. I guess you don't have the right tokens in your wallet or you didn't make the pair with the new factory.

Comment: no, it was  init_code_hash issue, fixed it